# PHP CLI - FTP Multiple Files

Tags: php, command-line-interface

Complete newbie and still learning.

I have PHP 7.2 installed on windows 7 and using it as a CLI to move files around.
I can upload files to several FTP servers fine.  I'd like to now to be able to upload all files within a folder.
I can do one at a time but it just doesn't seem like the most efficient way to do it.

Here is a sample snippet of my upload script for a single file upload:

```
<?php
$ostream = fopen("ssh2.sftp://$sftp" . $remoteFile_Official, 'w');
$ofile = file_get_contents($localFile_Official);
fwrite($ostream, $ofile);
fclose($ostream);
?>
```

Thanking you advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .

```
 <?php
   $dir = "/images/";

     // Open a directory, and read its contents
   if (is_dir($dir)){
     if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
           $ostream = fopen("ssh2.sftp://$sftp" . $file, 'w');
           $ofile = file_get_contents($localFile_Official);
           fwrite($ostream, $ofile);
           fclose($ostream);
        }
          closedir($dh);
       }
   }
?>
```

Comment: Hi Sanjit, I dont seem to be able to get it to work.

Comment: what is the problem now?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code

```
 // set up basic ssl ftp connection
 $conn_id = ssh2_connect($ftp_server, 22);
 ssh2_auth_password($conn_id, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);

 // Open SSL session
 $sftp = ssh2_sftp($conn_id);


 $Official = "/FTP/LPS Data/ATC/RHIL/20190119_RHIL/XML";

 $dir = "Z:\adminshare\Rosehill\190119_Rosehill Gardens\XML\Race_4\\";

 // Open a directory, and read its contents
 if (is_dir($dir)){
   if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
       $stream = fopen("ssh2.sftp://$sftp" . $file, 'w');
       $file = file_get_contents($remoteFile_Official);
       fwrite($stream, $file);
       fclose($stream);
    }
      closedir($dh);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps a bit more